# AutoHotkey: how to assign a command to the "Calc" key?

Tags: autohotkey

how do i assign commands to the "calculator" or "favorite" keys with autohotkey?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows.

Comment: It would probably be helpful to be more specific (i.e. XP, Vista, 7 (or even more specific, i.e. XP Pro 32-bit, Vista Home Premium 64 bit))

Comment: 7 in this case, but my problem has been solved.

Comment: With this script you can see what key was pressed: https://github.com/mihaifm/screenkey.ahk Its very useful and you can save time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The favorites key is called "Multimedia keys" in AHK.  The Calc key could be Launch_App1 or Launch_App2, but if not, see [Multimedia keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#Multimedia_keys) for detailed instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Below is how I set my `Calc` key to launch Google Chrome:

```
Launch_App2::
    Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you open a script, click on "open" and then view key history, it should show the name you can use to remap it there. Also, check the help file, I believe it has a list of common uncommon keys.

Comment: what's odd is that it shows the F key being pressed....

Comment: however, the "state" column has an "a" in it.

Comment: Is it possible the keyboard is just shooting off a series of keys? My friend had a keyboard like that. Does it work fine without drivers, and so?

Comment: I didn't install any specific ones, but it's a microsoft keyboard so maybe it installed some automatically though...

Answer (score -1):

You can also assign a shortcut key to the application's shortcut. The only caveat of this is that you need to use a shortcut key that Windows deems acceptable (such as CTRL+ALT+something) which might not be exactly what you like.

Right click the shortcut in question, and hit properties. You should then be able to assign a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I specifically want to use Autohotkey as it provides more flexibility.

Answer (score -1):

From http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181855

Select the shortcut for the application, Rightclick and select properties, select tab "shortcut". Click in "shortcut key" (which has none written in it). Now press the HotKey that you want to use. It will automatically appear in the box. e.g. if you press ^F12 then CTRL-F12 will appear in the box. Click apply and hit ok.

Comment: I specifically want to use Autohotkey as it provides more flexibility.